# Problema de pasar un metodo con datos de un form a otro form

Tags: c#, windows-forms

el metodo es el siguiente:

```
 public void ModificarMineria()
        {
            string sql = "";
            sql = "update Mineria set caja=" + txtCaja.Text + " , empresa ='" + txtEmpresa.Text + "', Departamento ='" + txtDepartamento.Text + "',ExpedienteJudicial='" + txtExpteJudicial.Text + "',ExpedienteAdmin='" + txtExpeAdtvo.Text + "',Concesionario='" + txConcesionario.Text + "' where IdMineria=" + txtIdMineria.Text + "";
            Funciones.ConsultaSql(sql);
            MessageBox.Show("Registro modificado con exito");
            dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
            txtCaja.Text = txtDepartamento.Text = txtEmpresa.Text = txtExpeAdtvo.Text = txtUsuario.Text = txtExpteJudicial.Text = mskFC.Text = txConcesionario.Text = txtColumna.Text = txtFila.Text = txtEstanteria.Text = "";
        }
```

este metodo va del form principal y cuando  quiero utilizarlo desde el otro form en un button

```
private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
            consultar.ModificarMineria();
            MessageBox.Show("Se Modifico Correctamente");

        }
```

los textbox como txtCaja.text me los trae vacio a todos

la forma de llamar al formulario principal  fue

```
ConsultaDatos consultar = new ConsultaDatos();
```

y la forma de llamar al formulario secundario fue

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            Mensaje mensaje = new Mensaje();
            if (radioButton1.Checked == true)
            {
                mensaje.Show();
            }
}
```

Comment: Y tu pregunta es....?

Answer (score 0):

Primero debes validar antes de crear la instancia del fomulario Mensaje, de lo contrario estas desperdiciando recursos creando una instancia, aunque el GC (Garbage Collector) despues lo recupere, pero para mostrar detalles relacionados debes pasarle los datos que quieres mostrar en el nuevo dialogo asignandolo a propiedades o pasandoselo en el constructor para guardarlo en esas propiedades o campos (fields) privados.

```
if (radioButton1.Checked == true)
{
    Mensaje mensaje = new Mensaje();
    mensaje.Contenido = "";
    mensage.Text = ""; /* Este será el título del dialogo */
    mensaje.Show();
}
```

Cuando el nuevo dialogo se vaya a presentar se inicialazará con el método OnLoad donde debs asignar la información a los controles.

```
public class Mensaje : Form
{
    public string Contenido { get; set; }

    protected override OnLoad()
    {
        txtCaja.Text = Contenido;
    }
}
```